# How to edit items in laravel collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new in laravel, I run a query and get rows from database and I want to edit a column of this rows before get them in view. 
So here is my code piece :

```
$callPlans = CustomerCallPlan::whereNotNull('id');

foreach ($callPlans->get() as $callPlan) {
    dd($callPlan);
}
```

And the output screenshot:

[image]

I need to replace all the 'x' characters with '-' of `numbertemplate` column..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to do this transformations always for your model, you can just add the following accessor method to the model class:

```
public function getNumbertemplateAttribute() {
  return str_replace('x', '-', $this->attributes['numbertemplate']);
}
```

Now everytime you access **$customerCallPlan->numbertemplate** you will get the converted string.

Otherwise just convert the column when you fetch the data:

```
$plans = $callPlans->get()->map(function($plan) {
  $plan->numbertemplate = str_replace('x', '-', $plan->numbertemplate);
  return $plan;
});
```

Comment: do not forget to return $plan

Comment: Why should that be neccessary?

Comment: Because otherwise, the `->map()` method will return null, and in my experience today, that's exactly what each fetched model instance will be(come). Before the end of the code block, add `return $varName;` to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could do the following:

```
$callPlans = CustomerCallPlan::whereNotNull('id')->get();

foreach ($callPlans as $callPlan) {
    $callPlan->numbertemplate = (whetever you need);
    $callPlan->save(); //save the changes
}
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: This is not recommended for large collection size so think of it if i am using some sort of pagination. and i want to do some processing without losing the paginated collection in other words i only want to process the fetched items per request.  i recommend editing items passed by reference

Answer (score 2):

You could use `update()` and `str_replace()` :

```
$callPlans = CustomerCallPlan::whereNotNull('id');

foreach ($callPlans->get() as $callPlan) {
    $callPlan->update(["numbertemplate"=>str_replace("x", "-", $callPlan->numbertemplate]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

By default php creates a copy of a variable when passing it to a function as a parameter. You can override this behaviour by prefixing the parameter with an ampersand, which will pass a pointer to the original variable to the function instead.

We can use this in a foreach loop inside the collection to modify the original item like so:

```
$callPlans->each(function(&$plan) {
    $plan->numbertemplate = 'xyz';
});
```

Comment: This does not work for collections of arrays in laravel 6.20. You need to use `map()` instead of `each()`.