# Laravel - Way to use `->map()` in conjunction with `->firstOrFail()`?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using the `->map()` function as demonstrated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37586898/3911632), but now I need to update the scopes that use `->firstOrFail()` instead of `->get()`. Or if you cannot use `->map()` with `->firstOrFail()`, how can I edit some of the values on the fly when using a scope to fetch an individual record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firstOrFail` will return a single result - not a collection. You can't `map` over a single item - but if you want to do something with the returned result in a callback you can wrap it with the `tap` function instead.

```php
tap(User::where('id', 1337)->firstOrFail(), function ($user) {
  //
});
```

Comment: Update: I am not able to use the `->trashed()` method on the returned model. Any idea why not?

Comment: @Dwight when I try to assign a value inside the `tap()` closure, the only thing that's returned is the property I set, and the rest of the model seems to have vanished in the JSON.

Comment: My bad, my original code was accidentally Ruby-inspired. If you did want to have a callback to do something with the model, you need to wrap it with the `tap` function and then pass a callback as the second argument. To be honest, you'd be better off just assigning the model to a variable and working with it that way.

Comment: Assigning the `firstOrFail()` result to a variable and modifying the attributes of said variable worked for me. Thank you for the help